# drop-down with country dialing codes and country flags

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a drop-down with country dialing codes and country flags something like listed in [google signup](https://www.google.com/a/signup/#0) for customers phone number in my signup page.

An answer to this is very helpful.

Comment: i want with country flag like in https://www.google.com/a/signup/#0

Comment: this is a Q & A site, not a code request service. Do some googling. Find something that matches your requirements. Play around with it. Then if you cant get it to work come back and state your question. OK?

Comment: Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204479/do-you-know-any-opensource-jquery-dropdown-menu-for-telephone-prefix) someone has develop something like what you are looking for.